# How to show data from two contexts in single view in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, dbcontext

I'm sorry for my poor command of English.

To display a list of users for each consultant, I need to first display the first name, last name, phone number and field on a page in ASP.NET Core 5.

To do this, I need to be able to merge `AspNetUsers` and `Students` tables so that I can take information from them and save it in the view model so that I can show it on one page.

But the problem is that I can not merge these two tables. I even used the Join method in Linq, but I got an error.

Needless to say, these two tables are already relationshiped and the only problem is the simultaneous display of information from these two contexts - one `IdentityDbContext` and other is `PlanContext`.

Thank you!

View model `Adminshowusers` :

```
public class Adminshowusers 
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName{ get; set; }
     public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }
     public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

And my action method that did not work

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ConsultantIndex(string Msg,string id)
{
    var data = await _userManager.GetAllUsersWithRolesAsync();

    var users = (from u in data
                 join a in _context.Students 
                        on data.Select(x=>x.Id) equals a.ID
                 select new AdminAddUsers()
                            {
                                FirstName = u.FirstName,
                                LastName = u.LastName,
                                PhoneNumber = u.PhoneNumber,
                                Field = a.Field
                            });

    return View(users);
}
```

Method `GetAllUsersWithRolesAsync()` is also pre-created and displays a list of all users along with their roles:

```
public async Task<List<UsersViewModel>> GetAllUsersWithRolesAsync()
{
    return await Users.Select(user => new UsersViewModel
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Email = user.Email,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            BirthDate = user.BirthDate,
            IsActive = user.IsActive,
            LastVisitDateTime = user.LastVisitDateTime,
            Image = user.Image,
            RegisterDate = user.RegisterDate,
            Roles = user.Roles.Select(u => u.Role.Name),
        }).ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change code a little, you can't join code in server with code in database. At first bring all students from db and after this join with another list.

```
    var data = await _userManager.GetAllUsersWithRolesAsync();
    var students = await _context.Students.Select(i=> new {ID=i.ID, Field=i.Field}).ToListAsync();
    var users = (from u in data
              join a in students on u.Id equals a.ID
              select new AdminAddUsers()
               {
                  FirstName=u.FirstName,
                  LastName=u.LastName,
                  PhoneNumber = u.PhoneNumber,
                  Field =a.Field
             }).ToList();

        return View(users);
```

Comment: Hey man, thank you so much for your help, you took me out of my confusion :) 